# How to get the "sharepoint group" of the user who has modified a list item using REST API in a single call

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, groups

I tried this:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$select=Editor/group,Editor/EMail&$expand=Editor/group,Editor/EMail
```

But this does not seem to work.

How to get the SharePoint groups of the user who has modified a list item?

Comment: You cannot get the SharePoint group from user field in single call using REST APIs. Alos, `Editor/group` is not a valid property.

Comment: Can you share a piece of code or a reference on how I can get it to work

Comment: I have added an answer below. try it and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the SharePoint groups of user directly by expanding user field (in single call) using REST APIs.

First, you need to get the user Id of the user who modified the list items using:

```
<Site URL>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$select=Editor/Id&$expand=Editor
```

Then in success function of above call you can use below code to get the SharePoint groups of user:

```
function getCurrentUserGroupColl(UserID) {
    $.ajax ({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + UserID + ")/Groups",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            /* get all group’s title of current user. */
            var results = data.d.results;

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log(results[i].Title);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here `UserID` is the ID you got from above REST call.

**Reference**: [SharePoint 2013: Get current user group collection through Rest api](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-group-collection-through-rest-api/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped. Did some changes on my own and got it to work